# php require not picking file needed

Tags: php

I have the following folder structure for my project.

```
/MelaClass
  ../xml
    interface.php
    ../grid
       table.php
```

In table.php at the top, I use `require '../interface.php'`, but I get

> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required './../interface.php'
>   (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in
>   H:\wamp\www#MedICUs\MedICUs\MelaClass\xml\grid\table.php on line 3

Why is this the case?  `../` is one folder up right?

[image]

Comment: 1. Please show us the full error message where you also see the full path which it tried to include 2. Do you use IIS server?

Comment: It's one folder up from the folder containing table.php to the folder containing interface.php; but not necessarily from the current working directory (getcwd()) to the folder containing interface.php

Comment: Use `require __DIR__ . '/../interface.php'` if you don't know your current working directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
dirname(dirname( __ FILE__)).'/interface.php'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
require dirname(__FILE__) . '/../interface.php';
```

It will take current full path to the file's directory, go up one level and include `interface.php`.